# Net::HTTP returning 404 when I know it's 301

Tags: ruby, net-http

I've got a piece of Ruby code that I've written to follow a series of potential redirects until it reaches the final URL:

```
def self.obtain_final_url_in_chain url
  logger.debug "Following '#{url}'"
  uri = URI url
  http = Net::HTTP.start uri.host, uri.port
  response = http.request_head url 
  case response.code
  when "301"
    obtain_final_url_in_chain response['location']
  when "302"
    obtain_final_url_in_chain response['location']
  else
    url
  end
end
```

You call `obtain_final_url_in_chain` with the url and it should eventually return the final url.

I'm trying it with this URL: http://feeds.5by5.tv/master

Based on http://web-sniffer.net/ this should be redirected to http://5by5.tv/rss as a result of a 301 redirect. Instead though I get a 404 for http://feeds.5by5.tv/master.

The above code is returning 200 for other URLs though (eg. http://feeds.feedburner.com/5by5video).

Does anyone know why this is happening please? It's driving me nuts!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs for Net::HTTP#request_head](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-request_head), you want to pass the *path*, not the full url, as the first parameter.

With that and a few other changes, here's one way to rewrite your method:

```
def obtain_final_url_in_chain(url)
  uri = URI url
  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    http.request_head uri.path
  end

  case response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection
    obtain_final_url_in_chain response['location']
  else
    url
  end
end
```